# Cannot download Ubuntu 12.10 from the Site

Tags: 12.10, downloads

When I am trying to download Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit, it is asking for a username and password of `gluh.nith.ac.in`

Thank You

Comment: Where are you trying to download from?

Comment: Seems like you are behind are proxy, aren't you? If yes, the username and password may be of the proxy server which have been or should have been assigned to you.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried alternative downloads:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

or the torrent:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent

Answer (score 0):

go to (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc) will download ubuntu 12.10

will start download iso 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

you can simply download an ISO file for ubuntu and then install it using wubi.exe if you are installing on win machine.

Comment: It would be good to have a link to the ISO file here.